# Have a Reactor Flux that behaves like a queue

Tags: project-reactor

The need is to have a Flux that acts similar to a queue that must be shared between different subscribers, where each subscribers can take it's own unique and unshared value from the queue.

Each call to next() should return a different value and the sequence should always be contiguous as expressed in this test and not start over.

Also parallel calls from parallel flux should't get duplicate values.

The sequence dao is a mock of methods that calls r2dbc api, so it has to be reactive methods like this. Therefore using the generate functions doesn't seems a possible option, unless there are tricks I probably don't know.

```java
public class SequenceServiceTest {

    static class SequenceDaoMock {

        private static final long DEV_SEQ_INCREMENT = 5;

        private final AtomicLong databaseSequenceMockAtomicLong = new AtomicLong(10);

        public Mono<Long> selectNextVal(){
            return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> databaseSequenceMockAtomicLong.getAndAdd(DB_SQ_INCREMENT);
        }
    
        public Mono<Long> getSequenceIncrement(){
            return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> DB_SQ_INCREMENT);
        }

    }

    @Test
    void test1(){
        SequenceDaoMock sequenceDao = new SequenceDaoMock(); 
        Mono<Long> sequenceIncrementMono = sequenceDao.getSequenceIncrement().cache();
        Flux<Long> originalSequence = Mono.zip(sequenceDao.selectNextVal(),sequenceIncrementMono)
                                  .flatMapMany(t -> Flux.range(0, t.getT2().intValue()).map(n -> t.getT1() + n))
                                  .repeat();
        //code that should be changed because tests fails
        WorkQueueProcessor<Long> queue = WorkQueueProcessor.<Long>builder().share(false).bufferSize(4).build();
        sequence.subscribe(queue); 
        Flux<Long> sequence = queue.drain().publish().autoconnect(1);
        //end of code that should be changed because tests fails

        Mono.zip(sequence.next(),sequence.next(),sequence.next())
            .flatMapMany(t -> Flux.just(t.getT1(),t.getT2(),t.getT3()))
            .zipWith(seqence.next().repeat())
            .flatMap(t -> Flux.just(t.getT1(),t.getT2()))
            .distinct()
            .sort()
            .as(StepVerifier::create)
            .expectNext(10L)
            .expectNext(11L)
            .expectNext(12L)
            .expectNext(13L)
            .expectNext(14L)
            .expectNext(15L)
            .verifyComplete();

            Flux.just("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","","u","v","w","x","y","z")
            .parallel(3)
            .runOn(Schedulers.newParallel("para",3))
            .flatMap(letter -> sequence.next().map(seq -> Tuple.of(seq,letter)))
            .sequential()
            .collectList()
            .as(StepVerifier::create)
            .assertNext( list -> {
                 SortedSet set = list.stream().map(t -> t.getT1()).collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
                 Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new) 
                 assertTrue(set.size(26));
                 assertEquals(set.first(),16L);
                 assertEquals(set.last(),41L);
             })
            .verifyComplete();


    }

}
```

The test fails because I get duplicate values in the parallel test, so there must be a concurrency problem.

Some code could be refactored like, switching back from .parallel().flatMap( ... ).sequential().zipwith(sequence).parallel(), which would protect concurrency from this flux but probably not from other flux instances.

Also Flux.zip( ) doesn't seem to create an issue with 3 values, but I guess it could have the issue since it's asynchronous.

Also one thing I noticed is that when you start .publish() and .connect(), then the flux starts publishing a lot of values very fast.
Doess the notion of unbounded/bounded requests have an influence on this, or do we have no other choices than having a lot of values sent and lost ? This is undesirable in that case. Also using a Duration to slow down would be a solution since it would limit performances.

#### EDIT :

With JDBC I can do it with the code below, but with R2DBC I can't do something similar because I can't call .block() from anywhere and keep state, and since spring boot excludes JDBC when you are are setting up R2DBC, I would have though there would be a way to do that exclusively with R2DBC.

I think I can afford doing that with JDBC because the cost of blocking every 100000 ids, is far inferior to querying the database with R2DBC to get an individual value each time. I haven't tested it though, but I can't imagine how it would be faster, than incrementing ids in memory.

Also I don't need to do a transaction for a sql nextval query because it's not transactional.

So I guess my quick win is to create a JDBC datasource in the back of spring boot, and get my sequence that way.

```java
public class SequenceService {

    private long sequenceIncrement;
    private long dbNextVal;
    private long limit;
    private AtomicLong virtualSequence;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        sequenceIncrement = jdbc.query("select sequenceIncrement from sequenceTable where sequenceName='mySequence'");
        dbNextVal = getDbNextVal();
        limit = dbNextVal + sequenceIncrement
        virtualSequence = new AtomicLong(dbNextVal);
    }
 
    private long resetDbNextVal(){
        return jdbc.query("select mySequence.nextVal() from dual");
    }

    private Mono<Long> next(){
        Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
            return virtualSequence.getAndUpdate(seq -> {
                nextSeq = seq + 1;
                if(nextSeq == limit) {
                     dbNextVal = getDbNextVal();
                     limit = dbNextVal + sequenceIncrement;
                     nextSeq = dbNextVal;   
                }
                return nextSeq;
        });
    }  
}
```

Comment: there is a lot to unpack here and the initial question (behaves like a queue) makes me think you're trying to go against the tide. maybe starting from what you are actually trying to achieve would help? I'm guessing you have x values to insert in DB and you want 1 sequence number generated per value, perform the INSERT and avoiding generating more than x sequence numbers?

Comment: The application transforms input files into text flat output files. Each line has a field that gets a sequence id that must be unique, and is provided by a database sequence. The db sequence as an increment, which allows to reserve a range of IDs, without having to query the vase for each id.

Comment: The db sequence has an increment of 100000, this allow to reserve a range of IDs, like 1100000 to 1199999 and we build intermediate values in memory 1100001 1100002 up to 1199999, then we query the base for next sequence and maybe get 1400000 because maybe another server instance got 1200000 already. The "Flux<Long> originalSequence = ...".

Comment: So the idea would be to query the database as few as possible and waste as few IDs as possible. We are not polling for new files with reactor yet, so a new reactive chain instance is created for each file. This is were we would need to keep the state of the sequence flux. Also probably we should try to get values from the sequence in only one place, instead of using sequence.next() in different parts, so this would need refactor, but I was hoping we could do without this for a while.